How to amend ".idea/workspace.xml" without overwriting every other setting
I have the following situation: we need to add a certain setting to every new/existing IntelliJ project - specifically the setting to run the formatter / optimize imports on every save.
These settings however are project-scoped, so a regular settings export does not work. These settings are stored in the ".idea/workspace.xml"-file of the project.
The following lines are relevant:
  <component name="FormatOnSaveOptions">
    <option name="myRunOnSave" value="true" />
  </component>
  <component name="OptimizeOnSaveOptions">
    <option name="myRunOnSave" value="true" />
  </component> 

Is there any other way to configure these settings without amending the workspace.xml in every single project?
Ideally something like a additional_settings.xml-file that adds its contents automatically to workspace.xml.
Thanks in advance.
